# FindControl in Infragistics webDataGrid

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I have ig:TemplateDataField that contains label.
In InitializeRow event handler I try to find that label with e.Row.FindControl but I get null.

I was not able to find another way to find my label. 
How to look for controls in WebDataGrid rows during InitializeRow event?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the column that you want to search in like `e.Row.Items[0].FindControl("ControlID")` where `0` the column index.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution that should work. 
note: Code is for an Infragistics UltraWebGrid control. The WebDataGrid control is the UltraWebGrid's successor.

C#:

```
protected void UltraWebGridCustomers_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.RowEventArgs e)
{
    TemplatedColumn col = (TemplatedColumn)e.Row.Cells.FromKey("HyperLinkEmailColumn").Column;
    CellItem cellItem = (CellItem)col.CellItems(e.Row.Index);
    HyperLink hyperLinkEmail = (HyperLink)cellItem.FindControl("HyperLinkSendEmail");
    hyperLinkShowDetails.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('This is the email link');");
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub UltraWebGridCustomers_InitializeRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.RowEventArgs) Handles UltraWebGridCustomers.InitializeRow
        Dim col As TemplatedColumn = CType(e.Row.Cells.FromKey("HyperLinkEmailColumn").Column, TemplatedColumn)
        Dim cellItem As CellItem = CType(col.CellItems(e.Row.Index), CellItem)
        Dim hyperLinkEmail As HyperLink = CType(cellItem.FindControl("HyperLinkSendEmail"), HyperLink)
        hyperLinkShowDetails.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('This is the email link');")
End Sub
```

Aspx code:

```
<infragistics:UltraWebGrid ID="UltraWebGridCustomers" runat="server">
    <Bands>
        <infragistics:UltraGridBand BaseTableName="Customers" Key="BandCustomers">
            <Columns>
                ...
                <infragistics:UltraGridColumn Key="NameColumn" BaseColumnName="Name" IsBound="True">
                    <Header Caption="Name">
                    </Header>
                </infragistics:UltraGridColumn>
                <infragistics:UltraGridColumn Key="EmailColumn" BaseColumnName="Email" IsBound="True">
                    <Header Caption="Email Address">
                    </Header>
                </infragistics:UltraGridColumn>
                <infragistics:TemplatedColumn Key="HyperLinkEmailColumn">
                    <CellTemplate>                        
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkSendEmail" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/EmailForm.aspx?email=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Email")%>' ToolTip="Send Email" runat="server" />
                    </CellTemplate>
                </infragistics:TemplatedColumn>
                ...
            </Columns>
            <AddNewRow View="NotSet" Visible="NotSet">
            </AddNewRow>                            
        </infragistics:UltraGridBand>
    </Bands>
    ...
</infragistics:UltraWebGrid>
```